# Angular 2 append html to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli

I have developed a angular cli project and got lot of forms to validate. I need to append form validation message out side of the **app-root** when it display.
My current implementation is as follows.

```
  <app-root class="" _nghost-c0="" ng-version="4.3.4">
  <!-- other html content goes here...... -->
        <form [formGroup]="form">
           <label for="name">Name: </label>
           <input type="text" [formControl]="nameCtrl"/>
              <div *ngIf="!nameCtrl.valid && nameCtrl.hasError('required')"
                     class="error"><validation-msg>Name is required.</validation-msg></div>
              <div *ngIf="!nameCtrl.valid && nameCtrl.hasError('badName')"
                     class="error"><validation-msg>Name must start with <tt>pee</tt>.</validation-msg></div>
         </form>
  <!-- other html content goes here...... -->
    </app-root>
```

I just need error message display as follows in the html when it display.
validation-msg is a component with simple template. That content must append to outside of the app-root.

```
    <app-root class="" _nghost-c0="" ng-version="4.3.4">
      <!-- other html content goes here...... -->
    </app-root>
    <validation-msg-content>
      <div>Name is required.</div>
    </validation-msg-content>
```

Comment: I don't know much of Angular, but it's seens like you're gonna need a "temporary workaround" to achieve that.
Maybe inserting some script tag inside the _if_?

Comment: You basically need to pass data from one component to another. You can read more about it here https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Please check updated question. it is not about sharing data between component. It is about appending component template to pout side of app-root element.

Comment: you want to send the validation message to a different component ?

Comment: It is not about passing validation message to anothe component. Please check Append popover in the body section of https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples. I need to add my message to body.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add something outside app-root. The components are organized in a tree structure. You are trying to work outside the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If  is the main component then you won't be able to do this. But if this form is itself a component then you can sent the error message to the parent component containing the form  component.

you need to use @Output in the form component and an event emitter that can emit the error message to the parent component. Now when the parent component received the event it can show the error message.

So the form component code should go like this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'myform',
    templateUrl: './myform.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./myform.component.css']
})

export class MyFormComponent  {
   @Output() sendData:any = new EventEmitter();

   validateForm(){
       this.sendData.emit({error});
   }

}
```

And the parent component HTML

```
<myform (sendData)="getError($event)"></myform>
```

Now you can define the getError method as:

```
getError(event:Event){
    //Do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Please check the edited question. It is not a passing data to another component. It is about appending html out side of the app-root element.

Comment: if `app-root` is the main `appComponent` then `validation-msg-content` has to be another module. I am not sure if you can do the communication between the two. The eassy solution would be to move the `validation-msg-content` inside the `app-root` and create another `component` for form.

Comment: Please check Append popover in the body section of ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples. I need to add my message to body.